# Mantaflow not working properly

Tags: mantaflow

I've been fiddling around with mantaflow in Blender and I can't get it to work properly.
I'm trying to fill a cup, but I've encountered some problems:

At first my cup wasn't holding the fluid, it was 'leaking'. I found a solution for this by making a different collider which is bigger so the fluid can't get through.

With the new collider the water doesn't 'leak', but it does come through the faces as visible on these images.
[image: fluid coming through faces]
[image]

As well as coming through the faces the water looks chunky and doesn't completely fill up the glass. I thought this was due to the resolution beeing to small (110). So I bumped up the resolution, but when I do that the cup won't fill up anymore.
[image]

The settings I use are as follows:

[image]

Can anyone explain why it works like this and how I can fix this?

Tahks in advance!

I'm using Blender 3.2.2 by the way.

EDIT

Here's the Blender file!

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @moonboots, I didn't know how. I've added the file!

Comment: it seems to work if you give a bit of thickness to your Effector, for example 0.3, have you tried?